# make the endDrawer in flutter scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make the Drawer of flutter scrollable so that user can see all the data in a drawer. i am calling the endDrawer as:

```
endDrawer:  ExperienceCustomDrawer()
```

the ExperienceCustomDrawer class is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExperienceCustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
   ExperienceCustomDrawer({
     super.key,
   });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Drawer(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
    child:Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 30, 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                      onTap:(){
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Color(0xffF1C452),))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15),
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                child: Text("Sea Food Experience",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: const Color(0xff4B4B52),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15),
              child: Text("Custom tabbar here",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),


          Flexible(
            flex: 2,

            child: Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15),
              child: Column(
                children: [

                  Flexible(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 8,
                            height: 1,
                            color: const Color(0xffF1C452),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Text("Experience",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 2,bottom: 2, right: 2),
                      child: Text(
                          "The sizzle and taste of authentic BBQ flavors in a cozy bistro setting. "
                              "Savor slow-cooked meats, homemade sauces, and sides made with "
                              "fresh ingredients.",

                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15),
              child: Column(
                children: [

                  Flexible(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 8,
                            height: 1,
                            color: const Color(0xffF1C452),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Text("WOW Factors",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),

                      child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 30,
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),


                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),


                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 6, 30, 6),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 8,
                          height: 1,
                          color: const Color(0xffF1C452),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child: Text("Location",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                              fontSize: 24,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                      child: Text("House # 11, Street # 65 F-11/4, Islamabad",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 6, 30, 6),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 8,
                            height: 1,
                            color: const Color(0xffF1C452),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text("Sub Host",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xffF1C452),
                                fontSize: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 9),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              "Zoya Khan",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),

                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 16,
                              width: 1,
                              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "0300 000 0000",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

i have tried to wrap the first container inside singleChildScrollView and ListView but it is not working.  make these changes will results in throwing render errors.as you can see:

```
return Drawer(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        child:Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
             

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
```

the error are:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
The affected RenderFlex is: RenderFlex#dc3b5 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=697.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add the `column` with `flexible` widgets in the `SingleChildScrollView`, which is causing the issue.

You can either

1. remove `flexible` widget and wrap the column with `SingleChildScrollView`

or

2. remove `column` and `flexible` widgets and replace column with `ListView`

Comment: thanks. the drawer is scrollable now. but i am using the webview and after removing the flexible and expanded widgets when i try to resize the screen, the text and images i used  in my UI overflow and throw a pixel overflow error. what can i do for that

Comment: if it is inside Row, You can wrap them in Expanded. You may need to manage its mainAxisSize though

Comment: well if i wrap any text widget  with flexible or expanded at any nested row or column. the drawer will not build.

Comment: can you add the updated code ?